# How do I only use the Intel HD 3000 card on an HP dv6?

Tags: intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I have a HP dv6 6195sp, the Pc have a AMD Radeon™ HD 6770M GDDR5 and Intel HD 3000. After installation ubuntu only use the AMD graphic card, how to install and use only the intel graphic card ?

Comment: Can you provide your DSDT info as described here? http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

Disable the ATI card in the BIOS, reboot, and the Intel one should be in use. Intel GPUs are usually soldered to the motherboard, so that you can't easily install or uninstall them (anyway, your's is already there).

Comment: ^^^IF the BIOS supports that that is.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can't disable the Graphics card in the Bios.
2. the Intel HD3000 is integrated in the CPU. Lets see how you uninstall it ;)

I read somewhere that you have to install the catalyst drivers and then switch the GPU to Intel. I also have to do this because the GPU fan is broken and I have about 10 minutes in Ubuntu before the PC shuts down because of overheat.